# Why is it necessary to specify \textnormal?

Tags: macros, formatting

I pose this question in the context of a specific example, but the question is more general.

On page 125 of Stefan Kottwitz's LaTeX beginners guide, a new command is defined for headings in a table. This is done as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\head}[1]{\textnormal{\textbf{#1}}}
\begin{document}
```

Why is `\textnormal` necessary? That is, what could go wrong if I failed to include this?

Comment: Because `\textbf` will just make the text bold, while keeping shape and family. So in an italic setting you'll get bold italic. `\textnormal` guarantees that it will always be the bold version of the normal font, no matter where you use the macro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The LaTeX kernel defines `\textnormal` as follows:

```
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textnormal}{\normalfont}
```

The instruction `\normalfont`, in turn, is defined as follows:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\normalfont{%
   \fontencoding\encodingdefault
   \edef\f@family{\familydefault}%
   \edef\f@series{\seriesdefault}%
   \edef\f@shape{\shapedefault}%
   \@defaultfamilyhook
   \selectfont}
```

So, `\normalfont` sets the font encoding back to its default, and also resets to their respective defaults the font *family* (usually `\rmfamily`, i.e., some serif font, as opposed to, say, `\sffamily` or `\ttfamily`), the font *series* (usually `\mdseries`, as opposed to, say, `\bfseries`), and the font *shape* (usually `\upshape`, as opposed to, say, `\itshape` or `\scshape`).

As @campa has pointed out in a comment, specifying either the low-level `\normalfont` directive or the slightly higher-level `\textnormal` directive is highly advisable as it frees you from having to make potentially invalid assumptions about the font attribute combination that's in effect at the time you need to change just one of the attributes.

Comment: Just to confirm, are you saying that ```\newcommand{\head}[1]{\normalfont\textbf{#1}}``` would have worked too? Or would I need an extra set of curly braces because ```\normalfont``` is a declaration?

Comment: @mhw - (Sorry, I had to change my answer after I realized that I hadn't read your follow-up comment properly.) Your second question is on target: You do need an additional pair of curly braces, to keep the effect of `\normalfont` from bleeding out to the remainder of the document. Do run `\documentclass{article} \newcommand{\head}[1]{\normalfont\textbf{#1}} \begin{document} \itshape \sffamily Hello \head{Hello} Hello \end{document}` to see what I mean.

Comment: That makes perfect sense now. Thanks for the updated comment.

Comment: So essentially `\textnormal{a}` is the same as `\textup{\textrm{\textmd{a}}}`?

Comment: @Pygmalion - The LaTeX kernel provides the definitions for `\normalfont` and `\textnormal`; `\textnormal{a}` is the same as `{\normalfont a}`. Part of the job of `\normalfont` is to reset the current values for the font encoding, family, series, and shape parameters to their respective defaults. These defaults are set by the document class that's in use. For the `article` class, the default font family, series, and shape are indeed roman/serif (`rm`), medium weight (`md`), and upright (`up`), respectively. In contrast, the `beamer` class uses sans-serif as the default font family.

Comment: Yes, my question was not precise enough.  `\textnormal{a}` is the same as `\textup{\textrm{\textmd{a}}}` if the default font is serif, upright and non-bold.  (I guess that in practically all cases default font is upright and non-bold, right?)

Comment: @Pygmalion - Yes, that's correct (with a few notable exceptions, such as for the `beamer` class, regarding the default font *family*). For sure, I know of no document class that sets a bold weight and/or an italic shape as the default.